# Communication of two application in same device

Tags: rest, wcf, soap, wsdl, microservices

There are 2 applications that need to communicate with each other. They are both running on the same PC.

1. Main Application (C#)
2. Helper Application (C#) -> launched from Main Application

Helper Application will modify some data used/contained by the Main Application. Can the helper application be a microservice? (not familiar with microservices, but I've saw this while checking on the net)

I found a helpful tutorial and was able to create a WCF Duplex Binding.
Now the Main Application and Helper Application can communicate.
I'm just wondering if this is a good solution (or a microservice is better??)

Answer (score 1):

> Can the helper application be a microservice? (not familiar with microservices...

Sure. *"Microservices"* is just the latest term that describes *distributed component-based network computing*.  It goes back a long way to the days of (and possibly further) *distributed COM* *(DCOM)* and *Corba*; *COM+* and finally *service-orientated architecture* (SOA).  WCF used SOA as a *best practice*.  In practice the only real difference between SOA and microservices is that the latter tend to adopt HTTP-REST-JSON as the transport/API/payload whereas the SOA generation is transport/payload neutral but generally using SOAP.

> I found a helpful tutorial and was able to create a WCF Duplex Binding. Now the Main Application and Helper Application can communicate. I'm just wondering if this is a good solution (or a microservice is better??)

Well technically you are already using microservice/SOA.

> I'm just wondering if this is a good solution

**No**.  The problem with SOA/microservices on the same machine is that they are very chatty; have a high overhead; and their message payloads quite verbose.  Both SOAP and REST utilise text messages (XML and JSON respectively) by default (which is large compared to binary).

If both client and server are on the **same machine** you are best to just use straight-up **named-pipes** and avoid WCF/REST.  Communcation under named-pipes are binary and so are very **compact**; named pipes run in Kernal mode meaning it is very **fast** and as an added bonus when communicating locally, **bypasses** the **network layer** (as opposed to say TCP which will even for LOCALHOST).